# I want to locate text under href tag and use it in assert statement

Tags: java, selenium

```
<p class="text-left ng-binding" style="">
<a href="#!/profile?userId=25" class="ng-binding" xpath="1">Unmani Joshi</a>
 Good Work!!
</p><div class="commentSectionClap">
```

I want to locate the text "Good Work".

Comment: <p class="text-left ng-binding" style="">
                            <a href="#!/profile?userId=25" class="ng-binding">Unmani Joshi</a> Good Work!!
                        </p><div class="commentSectionClap">

Comment: Hi Komal, welcome to StackOverflow. Please checkout the help pages on creating a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the text `Good Work!!` is contained in the `p` element that surrounds the `a` tag. You should be able to get the string `Good Work!!` by removing the text of `a` from the text of `p`:

```
string textToReplace = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Unmani Joshi']")).getText(); // "Unmani Joshi"

string desiredText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[a[text()='Unmani Joshi']]")).getText().replace(textToReplace, ""); // "Good Work!!"
```

`textToReplace` is just the text from the `a`, `Unmani Joshi`. `desiredText` gets the full text string, `Unmani Joshi Good Work!!`, then removes `Unmani Joshi` from the string. `desiredText` should equal `Good Work!!` now.